# How to add a loop to an IF statement for a password registry in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, passwords

I am trying to loop an IF statement for my assignment. I'm trying to figure out how to make my code loop back to the beginning of the scanner if the conditions were not met. I tried using For loops and While loops but I can't seem to figure it out.I thought about using a boolean instead, not sure if that would work.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
    final int MAXL = 5;
    final int Spec = 1;
    
    int SpecCounter = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Username");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String User = input.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0;i < User.length();i++){
        
         char c = User.charAt(i);
                  
                 if(c>=33&&c<=46||c==64)
                  SpecCounter++;
     }             
         
            if(User.length()<=MAXL && SpecCounter >= Spec){
                System.out.println("Username successfully captured");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Username is not correctly formatted, please ensure that your username contains an underscore and is no more than 5 characters in length.");             
        }  
     
    

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can surround it with a while loop.

```
boolean inputNeeded = true;

while (inputNeeded) {
   // your code
   if(User.length()<=MAXL && SpecCounter >= Spec){
            System.out.println("Username successfully captured");
            inputNeeded = false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Username is not correctly formatted, please ensure that your username contains an underscore and is no more than 5 characters in length.");             
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get it to stop printing the following statement continuously. Should I use a break?

Comment: with the inputNeeded = false; it should quit the loop when the username is correct

Comment: will give it a go and get back to you

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried a different method I found on youtube that helped quite a bit.